# Java's serialization (Using extererlizer) is much slower under applet then webstart

Tags: java, serialization, applet

We are currently moving our Web start application into HTML + Applet application.
As part of investigating of poor applet performance we saw with a Java profiler that the 
CPU time used for serialization on the client took in applet ENV 10 times more than the regular web start application.

The RMI procedure is mainly performed in a Special Structure we have called VOElement 
Object. in this item we do :

```
private void writeObject(final ObjectOutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    outputStream.defaultWriteObject();
    outputStream.writeObject(getParent());
}

private void readObject(final ObjectInputStream inputStream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    inputStream.defaultReadObject();
    setParent((CompoundVOElementIfc) inputStream.readObject());
    getInstance().injectDependencies(this);
}
```

We tried to check the JVM and the system java properties but it didn’t helped.

We are struggling to understand what the difference between the ENVs-
 it’s the same JARS and the same JVM settings.

Comment: What does getParent() do?

Comment: To go slightly off topic; inbuilt java serialisation is devastatingly slow (but also very reliable; which is probably why). If you're looking for speed you may want to look at external libraries.   I've been very happy with kryo

Comment: *"We are currently moving our Web start application into HTML + Applet application"*  My commiserations.  It will be a painful journey, and it (the applet) will continue to be painful after you think you have it successfully deployed.